# Related But Independent Concepts

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm looking for a word that states that two different concepts, although related, can vary independently from each other. For example, "politics and economics in a country are *XXX* to each other", where *XXX* is the word I'm looking for.

I've heard it in technical/scientific contexts, it has a certain *geometrical* ring to it. It's not "parallel", nor "perpendicular", and I can't quite remember it.

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment? how can I improve my question?

Comment: "Complementary" or "complements"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for the word *orthogonal*; however, it doesn't really imply the "although profoundly related" part (except insofar as we're not likely to need to clarify that two concepts are orthogonal if they're already completely unrelated).

The English Wiktionary [defines](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orthogonal#English) the relevant senses this way:

> 4. (*software engineering*) Of two or more aspects of a problem, able to be treated separately.
> 5. Of two or more problems or subjects, independent of or irrelevant to each other.

Comment: That's it! thanks for your answer, and for clarifying that the concepts are not _necessarily_ related (although they _can_ be aspects of the same problem, as stated in the software engineering definition).